# Python: Running a function on all points in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of cartesian points along contour lines and convert them to polar coordinates. I'm trying to run a function to convert them to polar, one for the length and one for the angle. However when I run the function it only results in one output, so it only runs on one point in the list. Here is the code:

```
def Polar(x1,y1):
    return math.sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2)
# ---------------------------------------pnt only pulls one point (x,y)
for pnt in part_list:
    print Polar(pnt[0] ,pnt[1])


polarcoord= Polar(pnt[0], pnt[1])

def pheta(x2,y2):                                                             
    return math.atan (y2/x2)

for pnt in part_list:                                                       
    print pheta(pnt[1], pnt[0])

thetacoord = pheta(pnt[1], pnt[0])

thetafinal = math.degrees(thetacoord)
```

The part_list is the list of Cartesian points from the contour line. The list is like 20,000 points long or so. I'm wondering how to get the polar coordinate (length) and the thetafinal (angle) for all the points in the list. It should be noted I am very new to Python.

Comment: Always use atan2() for angle calculation. Try to define all your functions in one place -- it improves readability.  Polar coordinates are relative to an origin.  Is your origin *really* at {0,0}?

Comment: You had tags for [tag:arcgis-desktop] and [tag:arcpy] but make no mention of either in your question, and so I removed them.  As it stands, this looks to be a pure Python question.

Comment: Changed to atan2() and yes the origin is {0,0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Polar(x1,y1):
    return math.sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2)

def pheta(x2,y2):                                                             
    return math.atan (y2/x2)

polarcoords = []
thetacoords = []

for pnt in part_list:
    polarcoords.append(Polar(pnt[0], pnt[1]))
    thetacoords.append(math.degrees(pheta(pnt[1], pnt[0])))
```

Comment: @Thorpedo, note Vince's comment re. `atan2()`. I didn't look at the validity of your approach, I only addressed your looping issue.

Comment: I can't believe it took me so long to figure this out. This makes so much sense and it even helped me with another line of code which I did not mention here.